# How can I prove this claim about surjectivity and $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following:

> Suppose that $X$,$Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that there is no $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ that is surjective and there is no $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ that is surjective. Prove that there is no $h:X \cup Y \to \mathbb{R}$ that is surjective.

It seems so trivial, but I can't figure out how to prove it.
Does anyone have a hint? Thank you!

Comment: What do you know about cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: If you're allowed to use the continuum hypothesis, this just boils down to the fact that the union of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: Assume there is an $h$. Show that there has to be an $f$ or a $g$, by using that there has to be a bijection $f':X \to X\cup Y$ or $g':Y \to X \cup Y$.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use it, only when stated. And it isn't.

Comment: The continuum hypothesis is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Andres: But the axiom of choice is. :-)

Comment: And to Daniel, I know what cardinal arithmetic is. Or do you mean what it is in this specific example?

Comment: (@AsafKaragila The first few examples of Dedekind finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ that came to mind all had surjections onto $\mathbb R$, and I got distracted and did not add the comment.)

Comment: @Andres: Hmmm, yeah, that might be the case. I haven't thought about that.

Comment: @Arthur: why do these bijections $f'$ or $g'$ have to exist?

Comment: One of them has to; $|A\cup B| = \max(|A|,|B|)$ if at least one of them is infinite (if they're both finite, then you have to prove it by different means).

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that: card($X$) < card($\mathbb{R}$) so card($X \cup Y$) < card($ \mathbb{R} cup Y$). But now I need that card($\mathbb{R}$) $=$ card($\mathbb{R} \cup Y$). Why is this?

Comment: What you need is $$(\operatorname{card} X < \operatorname{card}\mathbb{R}\land \operatorname{card} Y < \operatorname{card}\mathbb{R})\implies \operatorname{card} (X\cup Y) < \operatorname{card}\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: @Arthur tnx for the help!

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I'll try it that way as well. Tnx

Comment: In [these notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/settheorypart2.pdf), theorem 4 (with propositions 5 and 6) proves the comment of Arhur, if a reference is needed.

Comment: @Asaf: Choice is not needed either.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a choice-free argument: We use that $\mathbb R$ is in bijection with its square, and therefore we may suppose that $\pi:A\cup B\to\mathbb R^2$ is onto, and need to produce a surjection from either $A$ or $B$ onto $\mathbb R$. Start by defining $\sigma:A\to\mathbb R$ by $\sigma(a)=x$ iff for some $y$, $\pi(a)=(x,y)$. If this map is not onto, and $x_0$ is not in the range, then whenever $\pi(b)=(x_0, y)$ for some $y$, necessarily $b\in B$. Accordingly, define $\rho:B\to\mathbb R$ by $\rho(b)=0$ unless for some $y$, $\pi(b)=(x_0,y)$, in which case $\rho (b)=y$. This map is onto.

Comment: Very nice. Reminds me of Uri Abraham's generalization of Specker's lemma that he suggested during the final days of writing my M.Sc. thesis (which generalized Lemma 3.9 there). Now I feel ashamed that I didn't remember it! :-)